# Does the group $\langle a,b,c \mathbin | a^2b^2c^2=1\rangle $ have $\mathbb{Z} \times F_2$ as a subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $F_2$ denote the free group of rank two and consider the group $G=\langle a,b,c \mathbin | a^2b^2c^2=1\rangle$ which is the fundamental group of the connected sum of three projective planes.  Does $G$ have $\mathbb{Z} \times F_2$ as a subgroup?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is `no'.  No hyperbolic group contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.  To give some more details, the action of $\Gamma=\pi_1(3\mathbb{R}P^2)$ on the hyperbolic plane is free, discrete, and every element acts loxodromically.  Commuting elements must have a common axis, but $\mathbb{Z}^2$ cannot act freely and discretely on the real line.

Comment: Hey Henry, thanks for the answer.  Does $F_2 \times \mathbb{Z}$ have $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as a subgroup?

Comment: @dan Yes, of course, because $F_2$ has $\mathbb{Z}$ as subgroup.